# How to get share count of a youtube video using youtube api?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-channels

I'm using youtube to retrive some data on a youtube channel (title, id, keywords, lenght, publication-date, ...)

I want to know how to get the share count of each video in this channel.
I want to build a "top 10 most shared video" of a specific channel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the YouTube Analytics API:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/

There is a metric for retrieving the share count (`shares`). Use dimensions (`dimensions=video&metric=shares`). Alternatively, use filters if you want to retrieve the share count for a specific video: `video==Zhawgd0REhA`. For more info, see:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v1/available_reports

Comment: Can you please add a example or a sample url by which I can get an exact idea.

Comment: sorry to bump this old post. and Im following this https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs to get the video statistics (view, like, dislike) but I couldnt see 'shares'. is there a way to get 'shares' using this approach..? any help is very much appreciated. thank you